# Data from array into html combobox

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, oop

I have 2 arrays inside the class Continente..both public and i populate the arrays with records from mysql database.

```
class Continente{
    public $continente = array();
    public $tari= array();

}
```

And i have an object for wich i call the methods to put data into my arrays.

```
$cont = new Continente;
$cont->setContinente();
$cont->setTari();
```

Now the arrays look like this:

```
 Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [Id] => 1 [Nume] => Europa ) 
[1] => Array ( [Id] => 2 [Nume] => Asia ) 
[2] => Array ( [Id] => 3 [Nume] => Africa ) )
```

and:

```
Array 
( [0] => Array ( [Id] => 0 [Nume] => Romania [idContinent] => 1 [Populatie] => 2500 )
 [1] => Array ( [Id] => 0 [Nume] => Bulgaria [idContinent] => 1 [Populatie] => 2200 ) 
[2] => Array ( [Id] => 0 [Nume] => Estonia [idContinent] => 1 [Populatie] => 1100 ) 
[3] => Array ( [Id] => 0 [Nume] => Japonia [idContinent] => 2 [Populatie] => 5000 ) 
[4] => Array ( [Id] => 0 [Nume] => China [idContinent] => 2 [Populatie] => 4599 ) 
[5] => Array ( [Id] => 0 [Nume] => India [idContinent] => 2 [Populatie] => 6000 )
 [6] => Array ( [Id] => 0 [Nume] => Egipt [idContinent] => 3 [Populatie] => 444 ) )
```

now i need to make a combox with the 3 continents , and for each continent selected i need to print the first 3 countries sorted by the bigest number in 'Populatie' .

So i can select the contries for the continents... i have Id=idContinent .

Now i really don't know how to do this. Write a method for this in php? As i already have the arrays... or html?

This is what i tried:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
              <div>
                <br>
                <select>

                    <?php 
                        foreach($cont->tari as $val ){
                            echo '<option value="'.$val.'">'.$val.'</option>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>


            </div>

    </body>


</html>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using public properties with setters? And public properties in the first place?

Comment: nope. i wanted to acces the arryas easy.

Comment: Then make them private and use getters. It's better practice. If you keep them public, the setter methods are pointless. To answer your question, just pre-sort the array before you output it. You've got plenty of options, consult the array documentation: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.array.php

Comment: i know..but that is not really important now. i can do that later.. now i need to figure how to put the ccontinents in a  select box and print for each continent top 3 contries by population below.

Comment: i use the setters method to get information from the sql database.. and put in arrays .

Answer (score 1):

If you can do it, I think you can clean up your data structure quite a bit and it would make it easier to accomplish what you are trying to do. If you store your information like this:

```
$data = array( Europa => array (Romania => 2500, 
                                Bulgaria => 2200,
                                Estonia => 1100 ),
               Asia => array ( Japonia => 5000,
                                China => 4599,
                                India => 6000 ) 
                                ...);
```

Then you may be able to eliminate the need for your "ID" keys and just use the array indices for your IDs.

Then you can just sort your subarrays by value using `arsort()`. Something like this:

```
foreach( $data as $cont => $pop_data ) {
     arsort( $pop_data );
}
```

Then for creating your combo boxes, use similar code:

```
foreach( $data as $cont => $pop_data ) {
    echo $cont . " Population Info:" . "<br>"; // or whatever
    foreach( $pop_data as $country => $pop ) {
         echo '<option value="'.$pop.'">'.$pop.'</option>';
     }
 }
```